# Passing jvm options using xsbt plugin

Tags: scala, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

I want to pass an environment variable when running container:start from sbt. So I have tried adding

```
 javaOptions in container := Seq("-Dmyvar=xxx")
```

to build.scala, as outlined in the xsbt plugin documentation. But this is having no effect when I run container:start. Can someone suggest what I might be missing?

Thanks
Des

Comment: Which version of xsbt-web-plugin are you using?  The mechanism for passing JVM options has changed since 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using xsbt-web-plugin v1.0.x, then your approach is correct:

```
javaOptions in container := Seq("-Dmyvar=xxx")
```

You can find a working example of this option in the [*java-options*](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/tree/master/src/sbt-test/xwp/java-options) test case.

*EDIT: See also [this example](https://earldouglas.com/ext/stackoverflow.com/questions/25948575/), which shows the above `-Dmyvar=xxx` used with v1.0.0-M7 in a Scalatra environment.*

With xsbt-web-plugin v0.9 and earlier, you'll need to pass your JVM argument directly to sbt:

```
sbt -Dmyvar=xxx
```

Comment: Am using it with the scalatra project and haven't been able to get it working with v1.0.x. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991296/xsbt-plugin-1-0-0-m7-and-scalatra

Comment: Here's an example that shows this working with Scalatra 2.3.0 and xsbt-web-plugin 1.0.0-M7: https://github.com/earldouglas/so-25948575

Comment: The example link above has been changed to https://earldouglas.com/ext/stackoverflow.com/questions/25948575/