# How to specify a jetty.xml config file for xsbt-web-plugin

Tags: scala, scalatra, xsbt-web-plugin

I have a project that uses the xsbt-web-plugin but I want to be able to customise the jetty settings. Is there a way I can specify my own jetty.xml file? I found the

> PluginKeys.configurationFiles

setting and set that to the desired file but it had no effect

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a *jetty.xml* config file using the `config` argument to `jetty()`:

```
jetty(config = "etc/jetty.xml")
```

If you need to specify multiple config files, you can pass them as individual `--config` arguments:

```
jetty(args = Seq
    "--config", "jetty.xml"
  , "--config", "jetty-https.xml"
  , "--config", "jetty-ssl.xml"
))
```

Check out [the docs](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin#configure-jetty-with-jettyxml) for more info.

Comment: But that is for a build.sbt. What if I have a build.scala file?

Comment: For a *Build.scala* file, you can add it to the `settings` of the `Project`: `lazy val myProj = Project(..., settings = Seq(...) ++ com.earldouglas.xwp.XwpPlugin.jetty(config = ...))`

Comment: I have updated the readme with a [full-configuration example](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin#full-configuration-sbt-projects) of the above.

Comment: I am using it in the scalatra project and cannot get version 1.0.0 to compile with scalatra. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991296/xsbt-plugin-1-0-0-m7-and-scalatra

Answer (score 0):

I use xsbt-web-plugin 2.0.2(the latest version) at present.You can do in build.sbt as following:

```
enablePlugins(JettyPlugin) 
containerConfigFile in Compile := Some(file("./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml"))
```

I hope it can be helpful for you.